# Sharepint document library design- customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I seek your help in customizing a document library in SharePoint site for a particular requirement.

As per requirement, A Student record will be created and will need to go through workflow to be approved. few relevant documents will also be attached to Student record. All these attached documents will also need to go through workflow and will need to be approved

Taking a an example: for a student record, we have 4 documents uploaded so there will be 5 workflows (1 for student and 4 for individual documents)

Can this be achieved using one document library?

What will be a good design/solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom list that stores Student Details and add a workflow to this list.
2. Create a document library and add lookup column of Student Details list and add a workflow to this document library.

This way, multiple documents can be added for a student and approval workflow will go through all documents added as well as student record. I think this will not be possible to achieve this requirement using only one document library.

Comment: How can I provide a common interface in this case so that User see only one page to create Student record and upload the data in same screen.

Comment: That will require custom development.